# The Leibniz integral rule

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, leibniz-integral-rule, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I've had problems applying the Leibniz Rule.

The professor's slides say:

Consider the following value function
\begin{equation}
\nu(t) = \int_{t}^{\infty} e^{- \int_{t}^{s}r(z)dz} \pi(s) ds
\end{equation}
where  $e^{- \int_{t}^{s}r(z)dz}$ is a discounting factor allowing to actualize of the flow of profits $\pi(s)$ and $r(z)$ is the discounting rate.

Then, deriving the previous expression with respect to $t$, the value function can be written in the form of the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation (using the Leibniz rule) :

\begin{equation}
\dot{\nu}(t) + \pi(t) = r(t)\nu(t)
\end{equation}

How do I get the last expression? From my math course, I understand the Leibniz rule as follows:

Consider, $y(t) = \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(s,t)ds$, then
\begin{equation}
y'(t)= b'(t)f(b(t),t)-a'(t)f(a(t),t)+ \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial t} ds
\end{equation}

Comment: The problem I have is: how can I compute $b'(t)$, with $b(t)=\infty$?

Comment: I'm gonna have $\dot{v}(t)=0- \exp^{-[r(t)-r(t)]} \pi(t) + \left( - \frac{ \partial \pi}{\partial t} \right)$. But I guess I've done something wrong. If you can give me the answer, I'll vote for that. Thanks. Btw, why can $b$ be considered as a constant?

Comment: Got it. This means that the correct derivation is: $\dot{v}(t)=0-\pi(t) + r(t) \int_{t}^{\infty} e^{- \int_{t}^{s} r(z)dz} \pi(s) ds$. And $\int_{t}^{\infty} e^{- \int_{t}^{s} r(z)dz} \pi(s) ds= v(t)$. Is that correct?